# Analyzing h264 100GB video stream

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, cctv

I have a big file, an h264 stream video of a CCTV.
I analyze this file with ffprobe and the result is this:

```
[h264 @ 0000000002d24480] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000002d24480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0000000002d24480] decode_slice_header error 
[h264 @ 0000000002d24480] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000002d24480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0000000002d24480] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000000002d24480] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000002d24480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0000000002d24480] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000000002d24480] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000002d24480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced Last message repeated 1 times 
[h264 @ 0000000002d24480] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000000002d24480] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000002d24480] concealing 890 DC, 890 AC, 890 MV errors in I frame 
[h264 @ 0000000002d24480] sps_id 1 out of range 
Input #0, h264, from 'E:\example_1':
Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 704x576, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc
```

I've two little problems:

1. Can I know if in the file exists on a specific date (for example, January 1, 2014)? Can I analyze the meta-data stream of the h264 ?
2. In the stream video, there are images of different cameras one after another cyclically. Can I split the stream video based on the cameras? Is it possible? If it is possible, I would also like to merge the separate camera clips into one camera video.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I know if in the file exists on a specific date (for example, January 1, 2014)? Can I analyze the meta-data stream of the h264 ?

No, because the stream is simply an H.264 bitstream with (simply speaking) one frame after another.

It does not contain any metadata. When you want metadata, you need a container, e.g. an MPEG-2 Transport Stream, which is commonly chosen  for streaming media, or an MP4 file.

> In the stream video, there are images of different cameras one after another cyclically. Can I split the stream video based on the cameras? Is it possible?

Apparently the stream uses a proprietary format. ffmpeg cannot decode that kind of multi-camera video. Usually, an H.264 Annex B bitstream only contains frames which belong to the same sequence.

You would have to write an H.264 parser (or start with something like [`h264bitstream`](http://h264bitstream.sourceforge.net/)) and split the NAL units from the bitstream into separate bitstreams, one per camera.

Then, in order to decode it, your bitstreams need to contain [SPS and PPS NAL units](http://www.cardinalpeak.com/blog/the-h-264-sequence-parameter-set/). In your stream, there are none, which is what the errors tell you, as the frames reference SPS/PPS that were never declared.

Comment: Occasionally at work I get security camera footage from clients. So far they have all been proprietary messes. FFmpeg has implemented decoding for a few oddball security camera samples.